# UIViewAnimation + set image will cause memory issue

Tags: ios, animation

In my application I am doing left, right, up down zoom in,zoom out animation with different images.

Here i have used method to change image.

```
 int j=7;
-(void)changeImage{

    j=j-1;
    if (j==0) {
        j=7;
    }
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BG_%d.JPG",j];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str]];

}
```

> Note: i am creating the custom animation so i don't want to use
>   `imgView.animationImages`

Here is my code for image animation

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:ZOOM_ANIMATION_DURATION delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
                        imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4,1.4);
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:ZOOM_ANIMATION_DURATION delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
                            imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            [self animateLeft];
                            [self changeImage];
                        }];
```

**Problem: So Whenever i set the Image then memory is increased 7.0 to 8.0 % is increased is there any better way.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use +`imageNamed` , as written in the documentation it caches images, they will be evicted only during memory pressure conditions. Try use `+imageWithContentsOfFile` If images will have the same size you won't see such a huge increase.